# Why can't ping localhost in macOS Monterey?

Tags: network, dns, monterey

I can't ping localhost/127.0.0.1 in my terminal.

I have disabled firewall but still not working.

```
$ ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3

$ ping 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4

$ cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

What could block the ping of localhost?

[image]

Comment: Works on my machine.  Looks like you need to provide more detail on what you have changed from your original installation.

Comment: Do you have installed a VPN?